# NLP: Classification giving wrong result. How to find out that the result from NLP Classification is wrong?

Tags: node.js, nlp, classification

I have started learning Natural Language Processing and have already started stumbling.

I am using `NodeJs` for creating my application with the help of `NaturalNode library`
[Natural Node GitHub project](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural)

**Problem**

I am training my document with several scenarios as shown below

```
/// importing package
var natural = require('natural');
var classifier = new natural.BayesClassifier();



/// traning document
classifier.addDocument("h", "greetings");
classifier.addDocument("hi", "greetings");
classifier.addDocument("hello", "greetings");
classifier.addDocument("data not working", "internet_problem");
classifier.addDocument("browser not working", "internet_problem");
classifier.addDocument("google not working", "internet_problem");
classifier.addDocument("facebook not working", "internet_problem");
classifier.addDocument("internet not working", "internet_problem");
classifier.addDocument("websites not opening", "internet_problem");
classifier.addDocument("apps not working", "internet_problem");
classifier.addDocument("call drops", "voice_problem");
classifier.addDocument("voice not clear", "voice_problem");
classifier.addDocument("call not connecting", "voice_problem");
classifier.addDocument("calls not going through", "voice_problem");
classifier.addDocument("disturbance", "voice_problem");
classifier.addDocument("bye", "close");
classifier.addDocument("thank you", "feedback_positive");
classifier.addDocument("thanks", "voice_problem");
classifier.addDocument("shit", "feedback_negeive");
classifier.addDocument("shit", "feedback_negeive");
classifier.addDocument("useless", "feedback_negetive");
classifier.addDocument("siebel testing", "siebel_testing")


classifier.train();


/// running classification
console.log('result for hi');
console.log(classifier.classify('hi'));
console.log('result for hii');
console.log(classifier.classify('hii'));
console.log('result for h');
console.log(classifier.classify('h'));
```

> Output
>
> ```
> result for hi:
> greetings
>
>
> result for hii:
> internet_problem
>
> result for h:
> internet_problem
> ```

As you can see in the result of the key work `hi` the value is coming correct but if I misspelled `hi` for `hii` or `ih` then it's giving a wrong result. I am not able to understand how does classification works and how should I train the classifier or is there a way to find out that the result of classification is wrong so that I can request an user to input again.

Any help or explanation or anything is highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Please consider me as a noob and forgive for any mistake.

Answer (score 2):

*hii* and *ih* have never been seen by your classifier before, so unless `natural.BayesClassifier` does some pre-processing of input, it doesn't know what to do with them and so classifies them using the [prior probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) derived from the frequencies of the individual class labels: *internet_problem* is the most common label amongst your 22 training examples.

**Edit 29/12/2016:** As discussed in the comments, it is possible to handle "bad" classifications by prompting the user to re-input data for which the classification confidence measure is lower than a given minimum threshold:

```
const MIN_CONFIDENCE = 0.2; // Tune this

var classLabel = null;
do {
    var userInput = getUserInput(); // Get user input somehow
    var classifications = classifier.getClassifications(userInput);
    var bestClassification = classifications[0];
    if (bestClassification["value"] < MIN_CONFIDENCE) {
        // Re-prompt user in the next iteration
    } else {
        classLabel = bestClassification["label"];
    }   
} while (classLabel == null);
// Do something with the label
```

Comment: is there any way to find out if the classification has given a wrong result so that I can ask the user to re-enter the statement. many thanks for your insight

Comment: According to the documentation of Natural Node you can access the classifiers confidence levels using `console.log(classifier.getClassifications('i am long copper'));`. If your prediction soley relies on the prior probablities of your class it's confidence level should be relatively low.